# How do I configure two IP addresses on a specific vlan

Tags: networking

I'm not sure about the syntax here: what comes first in `/etc/network/interfaces` interface names, VLAN or alias? What I want is to setup two different subnets on the same VLAN (temporarily).

It will look something like below, where there's a 10.20.100.100/24 and 10.20.200.200/24 on the same VLAN (id 33):

```
iface eth0:1.33 inet static
  address 10.20.100.100
  netmask 255.255.255.0

iface eth0:2.33 inet static
  address 10.20.200.200
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I expected the Debian Wiki to answer this but it did not: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_One_Interface

Comment: After that configuration, and re-starting networking, what is the output of `ifconfig`? And what problem are you having? It is going to be complicated as you have 2 subnets on a virtual machine. Also, please add information regarding the host configuration and any firewalls you have configured.

Comment: And you syntax is off. inet static , allow hot plug, gateway ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know when and what changed, but you can now define virtual interfaces on vlans:

```
auto eth0.10
iface eth0.10 inet static
    address 192.168.1.61
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.11

auto eth0.10:1
iface eth0.10:1 inet static
    address 10.20.100.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0.10:2
iface eth0.10:2 inet static
    address 10.20.100.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Think of vlan interfaces as physical interfaces. You add virtual interfaces to the "physical" interface.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is actually not supported. What you can do is add several `up` or `post-up` stanzas which can then add addresses to an interface. I opted for this solution:

```
auto eth0.10
iface eth0.10 inet static
    address 192.168.1.61
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    post-up ip address add 192.168.1.62 dev $IFACE
```