# WHERE to add more IPv6 addresses

Tags: upstart, reboot, systemd

I have a script to add many new IPv6 addresses on *reboot* and that code is in `/etc/rc.local`.  The problem with this is that service processes (such as DNS server and web server) get started before the IP addresses are added.

*Where should I put this code to add these IPv6 addresses **before** any services are started?*

---

Edit:

For those who want to know what my code is doing:

```
for a in 2001:db8::{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}/64 ; do
   ip addr add dev eth0 "${a}"
done
```

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces`, though I'm unsure how you add "many" new IP addresses.

Comment: "add many" is a MS terminology for having aliases inside VLAN while using static IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining virtual interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0.10
iface eth0.10 inet static
    address 192.168.1.61
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.11

auto eth0.10:1
iface eth0.10:1 inet static
    address 10.20.100.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0.10:2
iface eth0.10:2 inet static
    address 10.20.100.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

From [How do I configure two IP addresses on a specific vlan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390337/how-do-i-configure-two-ip-addresses-on-a-specific-vlan)

**update**

Okay, have you seen another answer from that topic:

```
auto eth0.10
iface eth0.10 inet static
    address 192.168.1.61
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    post-up ip address add 192.168.1.62 dev $IFACE
```

It looks very similar to your script... And can run custom scripts.

Comment: i do not want to configure multiple virtual interfaces

Comment: and i am adding IPv6 ... see code i added to my Q

Comment: there were other answers i looked at in other questions but, due to the large number of addresses, coding it as a script loop seemed better than adding 1024 lines to a config file ... easier to maintain